# Make UITableView movable and selectable

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I know there is an 'editing' property for UITableView which puts it into an editing mode (cells are movable and/or deletable), but how would make a UITableView both selectable in the normal way, and movable?

So if the user taps and holds, he can move the cell up and down.. but if he just taps, then the cell gets selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out something https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController

It's open source so you can check the implementation, but the basic idea (i'm assuming from when I've done this, the link above may be slightly different) is

1. Add a long press gesture recognizer to the table view
2. When long press is recognized, create a UIView which represents the cell you are dragging, and move cells from underneath it as it is dragged

Comment: great, that looks exactly like what i might need.